# Regex to match a URL based up on a word

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a javascript regular expression to match URLs which have the word **-booker** in it.

URLs are generally like:

```
http://domain.local/htmlforms/mforms/product1-booker.html
http://domain.local/htmlforms/mforms/product2-booker.html
http://domain.local/htmlforms/mforms/product3.html
http://domain.local/htmlforms/mforms/product4.html
```

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried anything? start reading regex from here :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
https?\:\/{2}[\w\.]+(\/[\w]+)+\-booker(\/[\w]+|\.[\w]+)
```

This will match

- http with an optional `s`.
- two forward slashes.
- A word like item, or a full stop one or more times.
- A forward slash or word item one or more times
- `-booker` one time
- A forward slash or word item one or more times (second time, incase -booker is in the middle, this option can be removed if needed).
- A full stop and a word like character one or more times (for the file name.)

For an example, see [here](https://regex101.com/r/lD2qB4/1).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Also, please try:

```
/(?=https?:\/\/[^ ]+-booker[^ ]+)(.*)/g
```

`(?=https?:\/\/[^ ]*-booker[^ ]+)` is a Positive Lookahead - Assert that word `-booker` should be found in the url.

[**REGEX 101 DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/vO0yR6/3)

Answer (score -1):

I think this will help

```
/\http:\/\/domain.local\/htmlforms\/mforms\/\w+-booker.html/g
```